# Simultaneous Marginal Homogeneity Score Statistic in R

Tags: r, sas, generalized-estimating-equations

I'm trying to implement in R the score test for Simultaneous Marginal Homogeneity with GEE as described in section 2.2 of [Multivariate Extensions of McNemar’s Test - Klingenberg & Agresti [2006]](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/articles/klingenberg_agresti_2006.pdf)

The authors provide a reference implementation in SAS here (the first entry): http://lanfiles.williams.edu/~bklingen/sascode.html

```
data new; set ae;
subj=_n_;
array a{8} y1-y8;
do i=0,4;
 do j=1 to 4;
   y=a{i+j};
   s=i+j;
   output;
 end;
end;
keep i j s y subj;
run;

proc genmod descending;
class i s subj;
model y= s /dist=bin noint link=identity;
repeated subject=subj /type=ind; *any type (i.e., type=un) will give same value of test statistic;
contrast "SMH"  s 1 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0,
                s 0 1 0 0 0 -1 0 0,
                s 0 0 1 0 0 0 -1 0,
                s 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 -1; * use "/Wald" for Wald test;
run;
```

(data omitted here, but available at the link above)

I'm able to construct a GEE in R that outputs identical parameter estimates:

```
library(geepack)
library(data.table)

ae.vec <- c(
  0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  1,1,0,0, 1,1,0,0,
  1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,
  1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  1,0,0,0, 1,1,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,1,0,
  0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1,
  0,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0,
  0,1,1,0, 1,0,0,0,
  0,0,1,1, 0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0)
ae.mat <- matrix(ae.vec, ncol=8, byrow=TRUE)

n <- ncol(ae.mat)
ae <- as.data.table(melt(ae.mat, varnames=c('subj', 's'), value.name='y'))
ae[, s := as.factor(s)]
contrasts(ae$s, 4) <- rbind(diag(n/2), -diag(n/2))
ae[, c("i", "j") := list((n/2)*(as.integer(s) > (n/2)), 1+((as.integer(s)-1)%%(n/2)))]

fit.geeglm <- geeglm(y ~ 0 + s, data=ae, family=binomial(link="identity"), id=subj, corstr="independence")
```

The SAS code also outputs "Contrast Results for GEE Analysis" that contains the score-type chi-square value reported in the paper. `DF = 4, X2 = 5.05, P(>|Chi|) = 0.2818`.

I've tried to apply the score test to my model, but the value I get is way off, and also has the wrong number of degrees of freedom:

```
> anova(fit.geeglm, test="Rao")

  Df     X2 P(>|Chi|)    
s  8 26.255 0.0009499 ***
```

How can I replicate the score statistic calculation in R?